# Julia typeof in ccall

Tags: types, julia

Can someone explain why this ccall works when I explicitly specify the type, but Julia fails with "error interpreting ccall argument tuple" when I use typeof to specify the type?

```
type Foo
end
type Boo
    eq::Ptr{Foo}
    buf::Array{Float32,1}
    s::Array{UInt8,1}
end

function new_boo(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
    b = Boo(C_NULL,zeros(p1*2),zeros(div(p1,2)))
    eqref = Ref{typeof(b.eq)}(C_NULL)
    res = ccall((:myfunc, "mydll.dll"), stdcall, Cint, (Ptr{typeof(b.eq)}, Int32, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8),
                eqref, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
    b.eq = eqref[]
    b
end
```

If I print `Ptr{typeof(b.eq)}` and `Ptr{Ptr{Foo}}`, they display the same.  If I compare with `is()`, they are equal.  What's the difference?  I also tried assigning `v = typeof(b.eq)` to a variable first and then passing `Ptr{v}`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof` is a runtime function, but `ccall` argument types must be statically determinable when the function is compiled. (otherwise, Julia would need to insert a guard around every `ccall` to catch mis-matched types, making `ccall` much slower).

Your best option is to specify a fixed type in the `ccall`, as you discovered.

It is possible to use a [parametric type](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#man-parametric-types) for one or more arguments in the function declaration, which will allow Julia to compile a different version of the function (including a specialized `ccall`) for each variant of the argument type:

```
function new_boo{T}(p1::T, p2, p3, p4, p5)
    ...
    res = ccall((:myfunc, "mydll.dll"), stdcall, Cint, (Ptr{T}, Int32, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8), eqref, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
end
```

However, this is unlikely to be the correct solution unless you are either varying the C function name, or passing a pointer to some structure that has a type-tag.

Note that if you are reflecting a C struct with a `void*`-style opaque pointer, you can just write `eq::Ptr{Void}`.

Comment: What I actually have is 'struct opaque_obj **', which is allocates the memory in new_boo and re-assigns the caller external pointer.  The code I provided was the only way I could figure out how to make the c call -- not necessarily the best way.

Comment: `Ptr{Ptr{Void}}` is also available.